# Undefined method for matrix, string to matrix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, matrix

I am trying to work with matrixes; I have a model that has an attribute called "board", and its just a 4x4 matrix. I display this board in my view. So far so good. When I click a button, I send the param "board" with, for example, this structure:

```
{"utf8"=>"âœ“", "game_master"=>{"board"=>"Matrix[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0],        [1, 1, 0, 0]]"}, "commit"=>"Yolo"}
```

On the other side, in the controller, I try to recreate this board by creating a new gamemaster with board = Matrix[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]]. So far so good (NOT, I know that the param[:board] is just a string, that's my problem). Then, later on, when trying to iterate the matrix, I get this error:

```
undefined method `each_with_index' for "Matrix[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]]":String
```

Clearly, I bound :board to a string NOT a matrix. How would I go around converting that string into the corresponding matrix?

Thanks

UPDATE:
game_masters_controller.rb

```
def step
@game_master = GameMaster.new(game_master_params)
 @game_master.step
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js
 end
end
```

And:

```
private
def game_master_params
  params.require(:game_master).permit(:board)
end
```

game_master.rb

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
 attributes.each do |name, value|
   send("#{name}=", value)
 end
 if(self.board == nil)
   self.board = get_new_board
 end
end
```

Comment: Can we see the code where you assign the params to the board variable? A little context around the code maybe useful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
arr = params[:game_master][:board].split(',').map(&:to_i).each_slice(4).to_a
# => [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]

require 'matrix'
matrix = Matrix[*arr]
# => Matrix[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this does what I need. The resulting Matrix I get is a Matrix of Arrays. Meaning, when I try to get the value in column x, row y, I get an array as a result instead of a number.

Comment: @user3204217 What about now? Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty and not very secure:

```
class GameMaster
  ...
  def board=(attr)
    @board = eval attr
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would **not** run eval on something that gets submitted via a form. If the matrix is always 4x4, I would probably just submit the values in one long comma separated string like `0,0,0,1,1,1,0 ...`. Then I would use String#split to turn the large string into an array. Once you have one big array you could loop through it to generate an array of arrays that you can send to Matrix.new

```
string_params = 0,1,1,0,0,1
array_of_string = string_params.split(',')
array_of_arrays = array_of_string.each_slice(4).to_a
matrix = Matrix.new(array_of_arrays)
```

That should point you in the right direction.

Good luck!

Comment: This does seem a lot more secure, but, I'd have to manipualte the string, right? Remove the prefix "Matrix"?

Comment: Correct, you would have to make your form return all the values in one large string. You could do this with a simple text field or get more fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
(as the other answers mentioned, it's not secure to eval code coming from an input)

```
require 'matrix'
m = eval "Matrix[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]]"
```

=> Matrix[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]]

```
m.transpose
```

=> Matrix[[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]

Requiring the matrix.rb file will give you access to a lot of useful methods, check the documentation for further information.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html